# In C# Both const and static member varables can:

Tags: c#, static, constants

This was an interview question I was asked. I wasn't sure about the answer.

> In C# Both const and static member varables can:
>
> A) Be set in a static constructor, static method, or instance method of a class.
>   B) Change after a class has been initialized the first time.
>   C) Only be set in an instance constructor.
>   D) Be accessed without an instance of a class.
>   E) Be set by a set accessor of a public property.

I chose "A" even though I was unsure what they meant. I didn't know whether to pick A or E. Since I was running out of time I picked A. I probably should have picked E.

A) My problem with this one is that it says "instance method."
B) They don't change - False
C) Is the constructor of a static method or class called an "Instance Constructor?"  I know you can have a static constructor.
D) How can you access a constant without an instance? - FALSE
E) Not sure. I guess this could be true.

Can someone explain? thanks!

Comment: Well, clearly `D)`. Because all the other answers will either prove not true for either one (or both).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In C# Both const and static member varables can:
>
> A) Be set in a static constructor, static method, or instance method of a class.
>   B) Change after a class has been initialized the first time.
>   C) Only be set in an instance constructor.
>   D) Be accessed without an instance of a class.
>   E) Be set by a set accessor of a public property.

A) You can't ever *set* a constant, you can only define it. You can define a constant anywhere you can define a variable, but the very word *set* means this choice is wrong.

B) You definitely can't change a constant, so it's not B.

C) Incorrect, as above (A)

D) Fine, you can write `MyClass.MyConst` and `MyClass.MyStatic`

E) Incorrect, you can't change a constant.

So the answer is D.

Answer (score 2):

The answer was D. Any constant or static member that is public, protected or internal can be accessed outside the class without an instance.

Think of a const as a value type `static readonly` variable. also, marking them as const lets the compile use optimization at compilation.

Comment: actually the compiler optimizations you are talking about is time of evaluation...  `const` is evaluated at compile time while a `static` is evaluated at runtime.

Comment: @Steve The optimizations he's talking about, regarding `const`, happen at compile time, not time of evaluation. `const` is essentially a pre-processing directive which replaces all references to the constant with the value of the constant. If you write: `const int myConst = 1; var t = myConst; var o = myConst`, it will be compiled to `int t = 1;int o = 1;`

Comment: Exactly @Rob, I was not making the distinction between `const` and `static readonly`, just pointing out that const is preferred int the case of a value type 
"constant value"

Answer (score 1):

The answer is D.

A static member or property and a const can be accessed without an instance.

i.e

```
var x = Foo.StaticProperty;
```

Think of const as a static value that can not be changed at runtime.

E is incorrect because you cannot set a const at all.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question! I appreciate the feedback.  So you are saying that you don't need an instance to use a property or a static property?  Thanks! I guess I have some homework to do.

Answer (score 1):

Quick breakdown of the answers:

A) False, since `const`s don't get set in the static constructor.

B) False, you can't change the value of a `const` after declaring it

C) False, again, can't set `const`s after declaring it. You can set `static` variables in an instance method (and ctors) but can't change a `const` once you define it.

D) True - you don't need an instance of the class in order to access either.

E) False, again, `const`s can't be changed...

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question! I appreciate the feedback